# Galois extension of complete discrete valuation fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let L/K be a finite Galois extension of complete discrete valuation fields whose fields are finite and of characteristics p $>$ 0. Let v$_k$ be the normalized valuation on K, and v$_L$ the normalization of the unique extension w of v$_k$ to L.  G is the Galois group of this extension.

Define $\phi_{L/K}$ : [$-$1, $\infty$) $\rightarrow$ [$-$1, $\infty$) as follows. For s $\geq$ 0, let $\phi_{L/K}$(s) = 
$\int_{0}^{s}$ $\frac{dx}{(G_0 : G_x)}$, for s $<$ 0, let $\phi_{L/K}$(s) = s. And $\psi_{L/K}$ is the inverse of $\phi_{L/K}$

Assume L/K is a cyclic extension of degree p which is totally ramified. Describe the lower ramification subgroups G$_i$. And compute $\psi_{L/K}$.

Comment: I don't see what is your $G_0:G_x$ and $\phi_{L/K}$. Can you make it concrete with an example over $\Bbb{Q}_p$

Comment: $\phi_{L/K}$ is defined as above, (G$_0$ : G$_x$)  is meant to denote the inverse (G$_x$, G$_0$)$^{-1}$

Comment: No. A good introduction is [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification_group), before that you should know any Galois tamely ramified extension is of the form $\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/n},\zeta_{nm})/\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{nm})/\Bbb{Q}_p, p \nmid nm$, the difficulty are the wildly ramified extensions

Comment: here is totally ramified